# Information on board (airplane)

Tags: air-travel, airports, in-flight-services, services, premium-services

What kind of information is important or interesting to get from an Airline before/during/after a flight? There are already things like articles about your destination with suggestions of places to visit, restaurants, hotels, information about the flight like the height or outdoor temperature etc.

Do you have some new ideas, what's still missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question, as virtually any information could be important and/or interesting (see, for example, the wide variety of articles in in-flight magazines on all sorts of topics), but a few categories you could consider include:

- Safety information, as required by law.
- In-flight service information: food and drink available (for purchase or for free) and a list of other services offered on board
- Customs information: any required forms and details of the process at the destination airport. Sometimes, a video with this information may be shown before landing
- Entertainment information: a list of the movies/TV available (if not shown on an interactive screen), instructions on how to operate the system

Answer (score 1):

That depends a lot on the passenger.

Some comments on a couple of your suggestions:

The only flights I've been on where I didn't have a hotel booked at the destination were those going to Copenhagen (where I live), so I really don't need the airline to suggest hotels.

People going on a business trip or somewhere they have been multiple times before probably don't want suggestions to go see the standard tourist sights, so your suggestion of "places to visit" is also questionable.